# How do I go about actually projecting a speckle pattern?

Tags: optics, laser

I've been looking into speckle patterns and I can't seem to find anything about how to actually project a speckle pattern from a laser. All I'm seeing is techniques for speckle reduction.

I'm trying to project a pattern like the kinect does for depth sensing. I saw that ground glass might be a possibility but I'd like to get some input before I go down that route. Does anybody have any information that could help or a link to where I could learn what I need to?

Any information (the more the merrier) would be helpful on different techniques for projecting a speckle pattern for the purposes of structured light illumination based depth sensing.

Comment: Note that [laser speckle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speckle_pattern) is not the same thing as a grid of dots produced by a laser.

Comment: Oh. I didn't realize they were fundamentally different. How would I go about producing the grid of dots using a laser?

Comment: Can you edit your question if you want to change it? As written now, the answer is "shine it at the wall and you'll see the speckle pattern". An image of what you mean by "a pattern like the kinect does" might make things more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A diffraction grating will spread your laser pointer's beam out into a string of beams that will produce a line of dots on the wall.  Put a glass rod across the beam just upstream from the diffraction grating and you can turn the beams into fans that, on the wall, will appear like vertical stripes.  You can buy both from Edmund Optics.

Comment: S. McGrew, Thank you! This was the nudge in the right direction I needed.